# Google Cloud Printing with Thermal Printers

Tags: android, printing, google-cloud-print

I am trying to make Android application that is able to print recipes.
I would like to use Google Cloud Printing but I can't find any info about it working with thermal printers.

Did some of you work with Google Cloud Printing and thermal printers?
Are these two work together at all?
Is there good alternative thats cheap or preferably free?

Comment: follow steps 1 and 3 on this guide to connect your printer on the google cloud service: https://support.google.com/cloudprint/answer/1686197?visit_id=1-636436488921721262-1540258881&rd=1

Answer (score 3):

There are probably no thermal printers that are Cloud Print Ready. Instead, pick the thermal printer that otherwise fits your needs, and connect it to Google Cloud Print [via Chrome](https://support.google.com/cloudprint/answer/1686197?hl=en) or via the [CUPS Connector](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2906017).

Google Cloud Print refers to non-Cloud-Print-Ready printers as "classic".